# On physical click the button on one page, open another page and virtually click an item there

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a button on the main page of wordpress website. Now it just opens another page. When user physically clicks this button I want also some vitual click actions to be performed on a newly opened page. Probably I'm missing something.

Button on homepage is like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="http://localhost/mysite/anotherpage/">Go to another page</a>
```

Jquery code is (I used delay to let new page load (It didn't work:( )):

```
  $("#menu-invite-section btn").on("click", function () {
    $(document).delay(700).find($("#another-button")).click();
  });
```

I tried both `.click()` and `.trigger("click")`.
Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: $("#menu-invite-section .btn").on("click", function () {
    $(document).delay(700).find($("#another-button")).click();
  });

Comment: you forgot to add ".btn" before button because it is a class.

Comment: @Sunil Dora Yeah, that's true. Thanks. But still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link is within the same window, this will not be possible -- by the time the button you want to trigger a click on exists, the code that's trying to click it will have gone away (because the new page has replaced the one containing the script).

If the link targets a new window or tab, you can keep a reference to the `window.open` object and search within it:

```
$("a.btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newWindow = window.open($(this).attr("href"));
  newWindow.addEventListener('load', function() { // don't use arbitrary setTimeout values when you can listen for a real event
    $(newWindow.document).find('#another-button').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Note that CORS restrictions mean this will only work if the pages are on the same domain, and on a real server (it will not work on `file://` urls.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Beck! I haven't heard of this approach. 
Will this work if in my case it's http:// localhost?

Comment: Your solution totally makes sence, but it's still not working. Maybe I'm missing something. May that be because it's Worpress PHP-driven website, or something like this?

Comment: Without more information than "it's not working" I really have no idea what to suggest.  Can you maybe be more specific? Is the window not opening? Is the `.find()` not finding the expected element? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Right, excuse me. Window opens as it should. There are no error messages. 

It looks like I forgot one important thig. This new page button is a part of an item which is dynamically appended to the new page using AJAX when this page opens.

Comment: Ah.  Yes, that means you'll need to wait for that AJAX call to complete before you trigger this.  Easiest way would be to go back to `setTimeout` but I'm really not a fan of that, because network speeds aren't so predictable, you can easily fire too soon.  If you can directly observe the AJAX calls completion, do that; otherwise I'd poll the new window for the existence of `#another-button` in a `setInterval` and fire the click event when it shows up.

Comment: That's it. I applied .ready() on a container this item appends to and triggered "click" event. setInterval looks not that reliable in this case indeed. Thank you so much for staying with me until the problem is finally solved!

Answer (score -1):

Check this,

```js
$('.btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();                   // prevent default anchor behavior
    
    var goTo = $('#another-button').attr("href"); // store anchor href

    // do something while timeOut ticks ... 

    setTimeout(function(){
         window.location = goTo;
    },700);       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" href="http://localhost/mysite/anotherpage/">Go to another page</a>
<a id="another-button" href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp">google</a>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question asked -- it delays the opening of the new window for no reason and makes no attempt to trigger a click event in it.